# Returning value from inside of a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, return

Is there a possibility to return value from inside of a while loop? I need to return name value. Here's my code:

```
 public static String askFileName() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag) {
        System.out.print("Type a file name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        File file = new File(name);
        try {
            Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file);
            break;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            flag = true;
        }
        return null   // ???;
    } 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the point of `scanner1` ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is that your question? It's not good practice but it is syntactically correct.

Comment: who is stopping?

Comment: Instead of return null do return "value" and here you go ;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure to read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) article on how to ask a good question; generally you need to show you've tried something before asking a question. In your case, you can easily try a return statement inside the loop. If the program isn't working the way you expect, you can ask us to help you with it then.

Comment: @Berger missed that, already corrected

Comment: Change `break;` -> `return name;` and remove `return null;`

Comment: @saka1029 tried that before - still demands return (missing return statement)

Comment: Sorry, change also `while (flag)` -> `while (true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try some thing like below

```
public static String askFileName() 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String temp = null;

    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag)
    {
        System.out.print("Type a file name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        File file = new File(name);
        try 
        {
            Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file);
            temp = name;
            flag = false;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            flag = true;
            temp = null;
        }
    } 
     return temp; //return value here
}
```